# will i get stale data when i set readpreference as secondary and query with map reduce in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have replication set up like primary, secondary, arbitary.I am using the map/reduce concept for some queries in reporting module.I have a one question here.

I am sending the report related queries to secondary replica , set readPreference as secondary in connection level.So if we have map/reduce in query it creates temporary collection on primary.After creating collection on primary again making the query to that collection.Actually my read preference set to secondary it goes to secondary at that time if the data has not synchronized to secondary i won't get any thing right ?

My reports are taking huge time since i am having the lot of data.(Using multi level map reduce for one collections to process the data ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest you to use Hadoop that helps you a lot to map/reduce.

http://hadoop.apache.org/

I'm not sure if you're using python to do the map reduce, I assume that based on your keywords here but it could work in Javascript into the shell too or even Java.

Going back to the main topic, let's review map/reduce process:
Source data --> map() --> reduce() --> result

Due to map and reduce are normal functions, source data can be taken from any source and it will works. It doesn't matter if you do it in the shell (in my opinion is easier using hadoop or similar), db.collection.mapReduce must be read from the source you need to reduce, and you have to keep in mind it's only possible to output inline in a secondary server (not to a collection). This is the tricky part because you cannot output to a collection in a secondary server, the result will be there anyway, you will get the output collection, but don't try to output to a collection in the database.

This code works in your case:

```
res = db.users.mapReduce(MapCode,ReduceCode, {finalize:finalize});
db[res.result].find()
```

But don't use

```
“out”: “collection”
```

Comment: have you actually tried the syntax you suggested?  it'll give an error.

Comment: HI Maximiliano Rios,
I am using map reduce in java.I cannot return the data in inline since it is more than 16MB . Again i need to use map reduce on that newly temporary collection  at this time readPreference is secondary.My doubt is after creating temp collection in primary it wont synchronize with secondary right?
you mean to say when we use map reduce,read preference as secondary and "out":"collection" there may be a chance of getting stale data right?

Comment: But in my local machine i have tested like read preference is secondary, map reduce with out collection.Then i query the data to temp collection it has returned properly only.In my local machine having some lesser data?but production huge amount of data?
could you please clarify my doubts?
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how the java driver works but I'm quite sure if you cannot use any hint or additional parameter the driver will try to send it to a collection and it won't work. Unless the driver is smart enough to identify this situation, unlikely but possible. Of course if you have few data what it can happen is you get a small set that works perfectly in a normal database but impossible to move to a large database due to the reduction and limitation of 16mb. That's always the big issue in Mongo, it's necessary to rethink more than once the best strategy.

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide more information about what kind of reduction are you trying to do and estimation of granularity, large of collections and map you choose?

Comment: More questions, what's the architecture of your database in terms of servers and shards? I was thinking you could map/reduce more than once at a time in different shards to spread the process over all the shards. If the shards are well distributed and they use different machines/processors you can parallelize your map/reduce

Comment: In fact I think your only possible solution is to emit more than once the same key, due to the 16mb restriction. You could add one more level of grouping. Imagine the following example, I have 100 million products sold by country, and I want to group by country (my key) and emit this. It's nearly impossible bc I will have, let's say, 10 million values in one key, so the solution is to emit one more key (month for example) and reduce more than once.